# Jquery mobile How to remove border around ui-body class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Is is possible to remove border from class ui-body in my divs ? Please ignore dashed border on top its in code I have to remove it. What I need is to remove border around each div with class ui-body. Thank you very much.

Screenshot:

[image: ui_body_border]

HTML:

```
    <div class="ui-body ui-body-c">
        {foreach from=$category_26 item=CAT}
        <h2 style="color: #236EE8;" class="main">
            <a style="color: #236EE8; text-decoration: underline;" href="/{$country}/{$lang}/26_{$CAT.friendlyTitle}.html">
                {$CAT.Title}
            </a> 
        </h2>
        {/foreach}
    </div>
        {php}
            $this->assign('MaxNo',3);
        {/php}
        {assign var=number value=0}
        {section name=ArtCat_26 loop=$ArtCat_26 max=$MaxNo}
            {if $number == 0 || $number == 2}
              <div class="ui-body ui-body-d">
                {foreach from=$category_26 item=CAT}
                <h4 style="color: #236EE8;">
                <a style="color: #236EE8; text-decoration: underline;" href="/{$country}/{$lang}/{$CAT.ID}_{$CAT.friendlyTitle}/{$ArtCat_26[ArtCat_26].ID}_{$ArtCat_26[ArtCat_26].friendlyTitle}.html?do=article">
                    <b>{$ArtCat_26[ArtCat_26].Title}</b>
                </a>
                </h4>
                <p class="news">
                <span class="small2">{$ArtCat_26[ArtCat_26].ShortText}
                 <a href="/{$country}/{$lang}/{$CAT.ID}_{$CAT.friendlyTitle}/{$ArtCat_26[ArtCat_26].ID}_{$ArtCat_26[ArtCat_26].friendlyTitle}.html?do=article"></a>
                 </span>
                </p>
                {/foreach}
              </div>
            {else}
              <div class="ui-body ui-body-c">
                {foreach from=$category_26 item=CAT}
                <h4 style="color: #236EE8;">
                <a style="color: #236EE8; text-decoration: underline;" href="/{$country}/{$lang}/{$CAT.ID}_{$CAT.friendlyTitle}/{$ArtCat_26[ArtCat_26].ID}_{$ArtCat_26[ArtCat_26].friendlyTitle}.html?do=article">
                    <b>{$ArtCat_26[ArtCat_26].Title}</b>
                </a>
                </h4>
                <p class="news">
                <span class="small2">{$ArtCat_26[ArtCat_26].ShortText}
                 <a href="/{$country}/{$lang}/{$CAT.ID}_{$CAT.friendlyTitle}/{$ArtCat_26[ArtCat_26].ID}_{$ArtCat_26[ArtCat_26].friendlyTitle}.html?do=article"></a>
                 </span>
                </p>
                {/foreach}
              </div>
            {/if}
            {assign var=number value=$number+1}
        {/section}
```

Comment: `.ui-body{ border: none !important; }`

Comment: Hi Omar. You live there bro ?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find which style rule is being applied now. For that find the most specific rule in css, or just inspect the element in developer bar of your browser.

then once you find it, just remove the style from there.

If you cannot edit that file for some reason, add a more specific style somewhere

if currentstyle is

```
.ui-body{}
```

a more specific style can be

```
div.ui-body{}

body .ui-body{}
```

so these more specific styles will override the style

Only edge case is when using `!important` or inline styles.

if the element has some inline style applied with some javascript like

```
<div class="ui-body ui-body-c" style="border:1px solid red">
```

no rule in external css can override it, but `!important`.

if you use

```
.ui-body{
border:1px solid red !important;
}
```

this will override all styles including inline styles, which is against popular belief of javascript programmers, so its always safe not to use it as programmers usually assume inline styles can override all css rules.

Always try to use some more specific style rule, as practicing use of `!important` can take you to hard to debug issues as you move on.